# Use parameters in Hudson in configuration

Tags: parameters, hudson

I am looking into the "parameterized build"-feature of Hudson CI.

I would like to make this a parametrized build and then use one of the parameters as part of the svn URL.

e.g I would like to configure the svn URL as http:/oursvnserver/repos/branches/$PARAMETER

is this doable, or are there smarter ways to do this?

Comment: Try it and see?   Is this really a question?

Comment: This does not work for me, it seems hudson does not replace the variable?

Comment: Ah, it seems that the variables cannot have `_` in them, it works when using plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I do it. Except, I use it for the revision. Go for it.